# Working with time.process_time()

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

I'm trying to time how long a sort function takes, but I am struggling getting `time.process_time()` to work.

My current setup is:

```
start = time.process_time()
insertionsort(n)
end = time.process_time()

time = start-end
```

When I run this, I am getting this error:

> 'float' object has no attribute 'process_time'

How do I fix this problem? I want to use `time.process_time()`.

Comment: This is the issue. `time = start-end` don't name your variable with the same name as standard library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is in a part of the code that you didn't show. I assume that you imported the `time` module in the beginning:

```
import time
```

Which creates a name `time` that references the `time` module.

But later you create a variable named `time` that stores the time difference. At that point the name `time` references the difference and not the module. So when you try to use `time.process_time()` afterwards you get the Error.

This simple snippet illustrates the problem:

```
>>> import time
>>> time = -(time.process_time() - time.process_time())
>>> time.process_time()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'process_time'
```

If you insist on using `time.process_time()` the best way around would be to rename the variable that stores the time difference:

```
measured_execution_time_insertionsort = end - start
```

But you could also import the `process_time` function from the `time` module directly:

```
from time import process_time

start = process_time()
insertionsort(n)
end = process_time()

time = end - start
```

Both approaches avoid the name clash. However I would recommend you use the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module if you want to measure executions times, it's better suited for this kind of task than the `time` module.

Comment: To get a positive time answer will you need to make it  `time = end - start` instead of  `time = start - end`

Comment: @ThomasS. Yeah, I originally copied that from the question. However having a positive result seems obviously correct so I updated the answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: After running `import time` and `time = -(time.process_time() - time.process_time())` I get `Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`. Maybe because I'm using `Python 2.7.12 (default, Mar  1 2021, 11:38:31)`? If I try to do `from time import process_time` I get: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name process_time`

Comment: @user1271772 Yeah, it's because you are using Python 2. That feature isn't implemented there.