# How to calculate running time for a scikit-learn model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time, scikit-learn

How do I compute the time it takes to fit a model in `scikit-learn`?

It's pretty easy to report performance in accuracy, but is there a way to calculate how much time is spent learning a machine learning model?

Answer (score 0):

For general timing advice in Python, good answers already exist (e.g.: [Working with time.process_time()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599527/working-with-time-process-time)). Those should work fine here for simple cases:

```py
from time import process_time

start = process_time()
clf.fit(X, y)         # Assume clf is an instantiated model, and X, y exist
end = process_time()

print(end - start)
```

In the more general case, we may want to know how long on average certain models take to fit with respect to their hyperparameters. Here, [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) provides a `cv_results_['mean_fit_time']` to help answer this. This tells us that decision trees tend to take longer for higher `max_depth`.

```py
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10_000)

param_grid = {"max_depth": list(range(3, 13))}

clf = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier(), param_grid=param_grid)

clf.fit(X, y)
print(clf.cv_results_['mean_fit_time'])
# [0.03812594 0.04834146 0.05935068 0.06945467 0.07974615 0.0890358
#  0.09815149 0.10666809 0.11485486 0.12286725]
```

Or: [`cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) returns a dictionary with `fit_time` and `score_time`:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

cross_validate(DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4), X, y)
# {
#     'fit_time': array([0.05116796, 0.05008364, 0.04976106, 0.0510118 , 0.04988265]),
#     'score_time': array([0.00071454, 0.00047278, 0.00048947, 0.00048614, 0.00046182]),
#     'test_score': array([0.9375, 0.9255, 0.9325, 0.9375, 0.931 ])
# }
```