# How to calculate running time for a scikit-learn model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
# Creating holders to store the model performance results
ML_Model = []
accuracy = []
f1_score = []
recall = []
precision = []

#function to call for storing the results
def storeResults(model, a,b,c,d):
  ML_Model.append(model)
  accuracy.append(round(a, 3))
  f1_score.append(round(b, 3))
  recall.append(round(c, 3))
  precision.append(round(d, 3))

# Linear regression model 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
#from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# instantiate the model
log = LogisticRegression()

# fit the model 
log.fit(X_train,y_train)
#predicting the target value from the model for the samples

y_train_log = log.predict(X_train)
y_test_log = log.predict(X_test)

#computing the accuracy, f1_score, Recall, precision of the model performance

acc_train_log = metrics.accuracy_score(y_train,y_train_log)
acc_test_log = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_test_log)
print("Logistic Regression : Accuracy on training Data: {:.3f}".format(acc_train_log))
print("Logistic Regression : Accuracy on test Data: {:.3f}".format(acc_test_log))
print()

f1_score_train_log = metrics.f1_score(y_train,y_train_log)
f1_score_test_log = metrics.f1_score(y_test,y_test_log)
print("Logistic Regression : f1_score on training Data: {:.3f}".format(f1_score_train_log))
print("Logistic Regression : f1_score on test Data: {:.3f}".format(f1_score_test_log))
print()

recall_score_train_log = metrics.recall_score(y_train,y_train_log)
recall_score_test_log = metrics.recall_score(y_test,y_test_log)
print("Logistic Regression : Recall on training Data: {:.3f}".format(recall_score_train_log))
print("Logistic Regression : Recall on test Data: {:.3f}".format(recall_score_test_log))
print()

precision_score_train_log = metrics.precision_score(y_train,y_train_log)
precision_score_test_log = metrics.precision_score(y_test,y_test_log)
print("Logistic Regression : precision on training Data: {:.3f}".format(precision_score_train_log))
print("Logistic Regression : precision on test Data: {:.3f}".format(precision_score_test_log))
```

the output:
Logistic Regression : Accuracy on training Data: 0.927
Logistic Regression : Accuracy on test Data: 0.934

Logistic Regression : f1_score on training Data: 0.935
Logistic Regression : f1_score on test Data: 0.941

Logistic Regression : Recall on training Data: 0.943
Logistic Regression : Recall on test Data: 0.953

Logistic Regression : precision on training Data: 0.927
Logistic Regression : precision on test Data: 0.930

```
#computing the classification report of the model

print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_test_log))
```

the output:
precision    recall  f1-score   support
0       0.94      0.91      0.92       976
1       0.93      0.95      0.94      1235
accuracy                           0.93      2211
macro avg       0.93      0.93      0.93      2211
weighted avg       0.93      0.93      0.93      2211

I need also to compute the time for Linear regression model and another models in machine learning like KNN, Support Vector Classifier
so, my question is how to compute the time to knowe the speed of the algorithms and know which algorithm i have to use ?

Comment: Please do not open multiple questions with the same title asking the same thing. You can edit [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74818246/how-to-calculate-running-time-for-a-scikit-learn-model/74819139), and you can always [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on your own posts to refine or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

well most of the IDE's do that for you, but in your case:

use the time library:

```
# Creating holders to store the model performance results
ML_Model = []
accuracy = []
f1_score = []
recall = []
precision = []

#function to call for storing the results
def storeResults(model, a,b,c,d):
  ML_Model.append(model)
  accuracy.append(round(a, 3))
  f1_score.append(round(b, 3))
  recall.append(round(c, 3))
  precision.append(round(d, 3))

# Linear regression model 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
#from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# instantiate the model
log = LogisticRegression()

import time 
#importing the time library 

start = time.time()
#the current time

# fit the model 
log.fit(X_train,y_train)
#predicting the target value from the model for the samples

y_train_log = log.predict(X_train)
y_test_log = log.predict(X_test)

#computing the accuracy, f1_score, Recall, precision of the model performance

acc_train_log = metrics.accuracy_score(y_train,y_train_log)
acc_test_log = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_test_log)
print("Logistic Regression : Accuracy on training Data: {:.3f}".format(acc_train_log))
print("Logistic Regression : Accuracy on test Data: {:.3f}".format(acc_test_log))
print()

f1_score_train_log = metrics.f1_score(y_train,y_train_log)
f1_score_test_log = metrics.f1_score(y_test,y_test_log)
print("Logistic Regression : f1_score on training Data: {:.3f}".format(f1_score_train_log))
print("Logistic Regression : f1_score on test Data: {:.3f}".format(f1_score_test_log))
print()

recall_score_train_log = metrics.recall_score(y_train,y_train_log)
recall_score_test_log = metrics.recall_score(y_test,y_test_log)
print("Logistic Regression : Recall on training Data: {:.3f}".format(recall_score_train_log))
print("Logistic Regression : Recall on test Data: {:.3f}".format(recall_score_test_log))
print()

precision_score_train_log = metrics.precision_score(y_train,y_train_log)
precision_score_test_log = metrics.precision_score(y_test,y_test_log)
print("Logistic Regression : precision on training Data: {:.3f}".format(precision_score_train_log))
print("Logistic Regression : precision on test Data: {:.3f}".format(precision_score_test_log))

end = time.time()

print("THE PROCESS TOOK :",end - start)

"""
this will subtract the time we started the process in
from the time at the end of the process to show the time difference
which means the time the process took"""
```